# Convert all MYSQL Components to Greenplum Components in Talend

Tags: mysql, talend, greenplum

My company is migrating from MYSQL to Greenplum Database.

We have many jobs running through Talend and I have to manually change each component from MYSQL to Talend.

Is their an easier way to go about it through which all components are directly converted instead of having to convert each component individually?

Comment: Yes , you have to do that manually . There is not an other way i guess

Comment: You could experiment manually modifying the item files. If you can import them back then you're halfway to success. At your own risk. Normal DB components should work, but the queries, etc still have to be modified, metadata connections might broke, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With talend studio i am not sure theres is a way to automatically convert a componant but you can store credentials in the repo to make it fairly easy to re-configure the componant and make it a fairly easy process you can even create generic schemas that can be used by any db componant.

https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/repository-manager-user-guide/how-to-add-repository-connection

https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/studio-user-guide-data-fabric/setting-up-generic-schema-from-scratch

also to add a bit of extra value here there is some free training available on talend academy https://academy.talend.com/learn/register all you have to do is sign up for an account.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically one could create a Migration Task similar to existing ones:
https://github.com/Talend/tdi-studio-se/tree/maintenance/7.3/main/plugins/org.talend.repository/

There are many existing to get ideas from:
https://github.com/Talend/tdi-studio-se/blob/maintenance/7.3/main/plugins/org.talend.repository/src/main/java/org/talend/repository/model/migration/RenametDBInputToPostgresqlMigrationTask.java

I myself never tried this but I think this should be the most flexible way to do such. Use System properties to enable/disable this. You'd need to compile the org.talend.repository plugin, then replace the one in your studio.

Don't forget to remove the configuration/org.eclipse.osgi folder as it caches the plugins and your changes wouldn't be picked up!

If you're stuck you can also try https://community.talend.com/